# Word problem for polynomial equations: Volume of a cylinder given relation between radius and height

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, polynomials, volume

A cylinder has a volume of 324 cm^3. If the radius of the cylinder is 1 cm more than twice the height, find the dimensions of the cylinder.

I know that formula for the volume of cylinder is $V=\pi r^2 h$, but I do not know what to do next.

Comment: What is formula for volume of a cylinder....

Comment: V

=

π

r

2

π

r

V=pi r^2*h

Comment: $324=\pi{r}^2h,r=1+2h\implies324=\pi(1+2h)^2h$

Comment: According to @barakmanos  ’s suggestion, the equation is cubic in h. Is there any other info not included in your post? Are you sure this question is for your level?

Comment: @Allison I [have removed](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/961822/revisions) the test tomorrow part from the title - I don't think it is really relevant to the question. Since people are often asked to show their attempt when posting problems here, I have edited in your post the formula for the volume of cylinder. (Which you have mentioned in your comment.) If I misinterpreted something or changed your post in a way you do not like, feel free to edit it again.

Answer (score 4):

Knowing that volume and height and radius are related by
$$V = \pi r^2 h $$
and the restriction from the problem gives
$$r = 1 + 2h$$
Also, V = 324.  Plugging in these values and multiplying out the r^2 part gives
$$ 324 = \pi h (1 + 4h + 4h^2) $$
Rearanging gives
$$ 0 = 4h^3 + 4h^2 + h - 324 / \pi $$
A cubic calculator shows that the real answer is about 2.63.
www.WolframAlpha.com is a free tool that I like.
See picture

The answer is about 2.63066 cm for the height.
That implies that the radius is about 6.26132 cm.

[image: wolfram result]

Comment: It would be better to say "rearranging" rather than "setting equal to $0$"